# ExpansionTile or ExpansionPanel with horizontal scrolling using flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to implement expansionTile with horizontal scrolling Listview not vertical . So in this below image I want make this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLSUK.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is to use `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,` in your ListView

UPDATE

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Flexible(
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 100,
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text('No1'),
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  selected = 0;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: 100,
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text('No2'),
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  selected = 1;
                });
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      height: 150,
      color: selected == 0 ? Colors.red : Colors.green,
    )
  ],
);
```

Comment: I use listviewbuilder because I get data from api not static so there any example describe  this situation please like image !

Comment: ListView builder has also scrollDirection property which you can set to horizontal... And with all due respect do not expect anyone to build the whole page for you here. You asked about horizontal scrolling and I answered it

Comment: can wdith ExpansionTile fill screen device   or not

Comment: I make this but width expansionTile take width container = 100 finally I want when press on No1 and open ExpansionTile take size width screen not take width container are you understand me !  this image for understand sencrio your example https://ibb.co/x8jz8V0

Comment: Ok now I understand what you trying to do. In my opinion no you can not... Better approach is to change ExpansionTitle to normal List title. And when the tile is selected open another container underneath which is not part of ListView with whatever context you want there for each tile